# How to make this styled select overlay instead of push down elements

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I like the styled select that I found here: http://www.scribbletribe.com/how-to-style-the-select-dropdown/

The only problem is that it pushes down elements below it rather than appearing over them like a normal select would.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a link to a fiddle?

From what I can see, you need to wrap the `<a>` which is the toggle, and the `<ul>` in a div, which is `inline-block` & `position: relative`. Then you need to `position: absolute` the dropdown.

If you provide a link to a fiddle or codepen, I'll fork it and show you what I mean :)

Comment: I actually found a better solution and sadly don't have time to test out your suggestions at the moment (though I plan to later for my own enrichment). So I will go ahead and mark this the answer.